# Hover priority on sliding menu over h1

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

I'm having some issues with the sliding menu links. Each sliding menu works as intended, but if I try to hover the sliding link in the same horizontal space as the h1 text (the first one, the one that says "PERFIL"), it doesn't work until the cursor leaves the h1 area.

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="video">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<div class="wrapper">
<ul id="menu">
<li id="home">
<a href="home.html">PERFIL<img src="menu/home.png"></a>
</li>
<li id="3d">
<a href="grafica3d.html">GRAFICA 3D<img src="menu/3d.jpg"></a>
</li>
<li id="3">
<a href="audiovisual.html">AUDIOVISUAL<img src="menu/audio.jpg"></a>
</li>
<li id="4">
<a href="fotomontaje.html">FOTOMONTAJE DIGITAL<img src="menu/ps.png"></a>
</li>
<li id="5">
<a href="contacto.html">CONTACTO<img src="menu/contact.png"></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<body>
<h1><div id="video">VIDEO</div></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
.wrapper * {
overflow:hidden;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.wrapper ul li {
display:flex;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
.wrapper ul li a {
background:black;
color:white;
padding:5px 10px;
transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 45px));
transition: transform 1s ease;
text-decoration: none;
}
.wrapper img {
max-width:32px;
margin-left:5px;
}
.wrapper ul li a:hover {
background:black;
color:white;
padding:5px 10px;
transform: translateX(0);
}
.wrapper:hover a:focus {
left: 0;
background: none;
}
.video h1 {
font-family: verdana;
color:  white;
text-align: right;
margin-right: 5%;
margin-top: -280px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
text-transform: uppercase;
background-position: center;
transform: skewX(-20deg);
transform-origin: top;
}
.video div {
padding: 2%;
display: inline;
border-radius: 15px;
}
#video {
background-color: black;
padding: 1%;
display: inline;
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

---

[Here's a mockup of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZP5MW.jpg)

---

([Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ariel_Tapia/mreo160t/8/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the width of the `h1` element overlaps the menu. You can change the width of the `h1` and it should works as expected.

[See updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50hofexc/1/)

Comment: Thanks! Since the `body` elements dropped some places below the intended placement, how can I put them back?

Comment: You can use absolute position on the left menu, so body elements will go up

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but could you give an example? Been trying on my own but the left menu keeps disappearing.